# Testing jquery code inside angular component using jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test pieces of jquery code that are set on ngOnInit() of my angular app.These code adds and removes certain classes based on conditions that are identified using jquery functions.

Below is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if ($('#js-drawer') !== undefined && $('#js-drawer').hasClass('pxh-drawer--narrow@lg')) {
            $('#gf-header').removeClass('pxh-view-header--animate-narrow pxh-view-header--narrow@lg');
        } else if ($('#js-drawer') !== undefined && $('#js-drawer').hasClass('pxh-drawer--wide@lg')) {
            $('#gf-header').addClass('pxh-view-header--animate-narrow pxh-view-header--narrow@lg');
        }
    }   
}
```

and below is the test case that I tried.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
declare var $;
fdescribe('AppComponent Test', () => {
    let component: any;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('test onInit function', () => {
        const case1 = $('#js-drawer');
        const case2 = $('#js-drawer').hasClass('pxh-drawer--narrow@lg');
        spyOn($('#gf-header'), 'removeClass');
        component.ngOnInit();
        if (case1 && case2) {
            expect($('#gf-header')).toHaveBeenCalledWith('removeClass');
        }
    });
});
```

Do let me know if this is the right way to test..Thanks

Comment: Looks like Angular 2+ to me. You need to change `angularjs` tag to `angular` if that's the case

Comment: Where are things like '#js-drawer ad #js-drawer located? Are they in component template? There is no listing for the template. There are numerous reasons why you should avoid jQuery in Angular development when possible. One of them is testability. It will be hard to test properly.

Comment: These are not part of component template but located as global id's and classes